# Java JDBC and SQL database view changes

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am working on Java GUI application which connects to SQL database on localhost (I use XAMPP). When I change some entry, for example Age, I click on "Save changes", it is saved and changes are done in SQL database, but when I click on ">" or "<" to view next or previous person and then go back to the person, where I did changes, every entry is without changes in its initial state. But when I close the application and reopen it, all the changes which I made are done. This is part of the code where is mistake, I think. Thank you.

```
private void jButtonSaveChangesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
            try {                                                 
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                try {
                    String query1 = "UPDATE list1 SET " +
                            "name ='" + jTextFieldName.getText() + "', " +
                            "surname ='" + jTextFieldSurname.getText() + "', " +
                            "age ='" + jTextFieldAge.getText() + "' " +
                            "WHERE ID = " + jLabelActualID.getText();
                    stmt.executeUpdate(query1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println(e);
            }
    }
```

Code for viewing previous person:

```
public void LoadPreviousRecord() {
      try {
          if (!rs.isFirst()) {
               rs.previous();
               FillFields(); }
          } catch (SQLException e) { System.err.println(e); } }
```

FillFields():

```
public void FillFields() {
     try {
          jLabelActualID.setText(rs.getString("ID")); 
          jTextFieldName.setText(rs.getString("name")); 
          jTextFieldSurname.setText(rs.getString("surname")); 
          jTextFieldAge.setText(rs.getString("age")); 
          jTextFieldActual.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getRow())); 
          jLabelSlash.setText("/ " + rowsCount);
     } catch (SQLException e) { System.err.println(e); } }
```

rowsCount is assessed in SetResultSet():

```
rs.last();
rowsCount = rs.getRow();
```

[Image of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN9i5.png)

Comment: inside of your save function, you need to tell the program its old `rs(Result Set)` is out of date and the program needs to re-execute its select query.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to do it? I think I tried everything and nothing worked. I am just beginner. Thanks.